# Missing frames in H264 encoded video with OpenCv vs. VLC media player

Tags: python, opencv, h.264, vlc, frame-rate

I have a video that is encoded in h264. The framerate is of importance, therefore the video is recording a clock and I can see that the usual frame rate is 12.5 in the settings. However, when reading all the frames in the video with opencv and python I only have a frame rate of 6 for some seconds.

In the cmd it says
[h264 @ 0x42e76c0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x3594ac0] pps_id 257 out of range!

and some other errors.

If I countercheck with the VLC media player and forward frame by frame I can see that a second has more frames than measured with the technique from above - hence there are more frames for the same second.

Does anyone know where this issue comes from?

Thank you in advance!